# Can't shut down my computer

Tags: 14.04

When I shut down my computer, it shows that " mount: / is busy " and also shows "Will now shut down". But even after long time it displays the same.

What I want to do to shut down my computer?

Comment: `sudo halt` gives the same result?

Comment: Yes, sudo halt also gives the same result